# How to take and save a picture on Android phone without press the save button?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm developing an android app for the visually-impaired people, so it will be very convenient for them if I can take and save the picture automatically without pressing the save button after taking a picture. I'm looking for API from android developer website, but I didn't find any API which is helpful for me. Anyone who has any idea about how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the steps to save the image inside the `PictureCallBack.onPictureTaken` of your own Camera Activity.

Here's an example:

```
   @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera camera) {
        //Use imageData[] and save wherever you want
        File imagefile = new File(filepath); // set a file path
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imagefile);
        try {
          fos.write(imageData);
          fos.flush();
        } catch(Exception e) {
           //Something wrong happened
        } finally {
            fos.close();
        }
    }
```

Remember to add in your `AndroidManifest` the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement your own Camera Activity using the camera object and handle the storing the images after each capture.

The default camera intent options are very limited.